# How to convert PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone to DateTime?

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp, jodatime

This is a date which I get in my application:

```
String psqlDate = "2013-11-17 14:08:33+01";
```

What is best way to convert `psqlDate` to joda `DateTime`?

**[EDIT]**

I can use `DateTime` [parse](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter%29) method. It works fine with timestamp whitch have splitted information about date and time with T - `2013-11-17T14:08:33+01`.

This should work with good pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd...");
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse((String) obj, formatter);
```

What is correct pattern to PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone?

Comment: Surprised your code sees a `String` for the date, not a `java.sql.Date`. How are you fetching this from the DB?

Comment: in other words, why not `SELECT` it out as a `date` in the first place? Then you can use JodaTime's conversion routines from `java.sql.Date` / `java.util.Date`.

Comment: I'm not fetching data stright from PostgreSQL. I get data from Kafka in JSON format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a genuine Joda answer. Have you tried following pattern in `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat`?

"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

I see that your time zone offset is only specified in hours, not minutes. So maybe you need simple preprocessing and double Z like this:

```
String psqlDate = "2013-11-17 14:08:33+01";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZ");
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(psqlDate + ":00", formatter);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
    String psqlDate = "2013-11-17 14:08:33+01";
    Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'+'01").parse(psqlDate);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Out put:

```
    Sun Nov 17 14:08:33 IST 2013
```

Comment: What is the correct pattern to get information about timezone as well?

Answer (score 0):

[using the SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) 
Something like:
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss").parse()
to convert it into a java [date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object